# Error when using Great Expectations to read CSV from Azure Data Lake: TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'connect_options'

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2, great-expectations

I'm using Great Expectations locally and trying to connect it to Azure Data Lake.
I'm testing the connection by simply reading a CSV-file from the data lake using the Pandas.

The code produces an error: `TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'connect_options'`

Code to reproduce:

```
import great_expectations as gx

context = gx.get_context()
datasource = context.sources.add_pandas_abs(
    name="great_expectations_azure_test",
    azure_options={"conn_str": "<CONN_STR>"}
)
data_asset = datasource.add_csv_asset(
    name="taxi_data_asset",
    batching_regex=r"data/taxi_yellow_tripdata_samples/yellow_tripdata_2019-01\.csv",
    abs_container="yellowtaxis",
    abs_name_starts_with="data/taxi_yellow_tripdata_samples/",
)
batch_request = data_asset.build_batch_request()
data_batch = data_asset.get_batch_list_from_batch_request(batch_request)
```

The data lake has only 1 file: `data/taxi_yellow_tripdata_samples/yellow_tripdata_2019-01.csv"`

I debugged this and was able to confirm that GE successfully downloads data from Azure Data Lake to a StreamIO buffer inside Great Expectations.
The buffer should be read using `pandas.read_csv` but for some reason `connect_options` -parameter is passed to the `pandas.read_csv()` which causes the error

I didn't find a ready-made example for connecting GE to Azure Data Lake so I'm asking if there's something wrong with my configuration or is this a problem with Great Expectations?

The code is combined from snippets from these resources in the GE documentation:

[How to set up Great Expectations to work with data in Azure Blob Storage](https://docs.greatexpectations.io/docs/guides/setup/optional_dependencies/cloud/how_to_set_up_gx_to_work_with_data_in_abs/)

[How to connect to data on Azure Blob Storage using Pandas](https://docs.greatexpectations.io/docs/guides/connecting_to_your_data/fluent/cloud/how_to_connect_to_data_on_azure_blob_storage_using_pandas)

[How to request data from a Data Asset](https://docs.greatexpectations.io/docs/guides/connecting_to_your_data/fluent/batch_requests/how_to_request_data_from_a_data_asset)

Note: I know that I could just download the files from the data lake using some other client, and pass that to Great Expectations as plain CSV. I'm just starting out with GE and at this point would prefer to use the built-in way to access Azure Data Lake but I'll look into that if the built-in way is not feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in Great Expectations version 0.16.10 and now the code works as is